# Is "an older Swedish relatives" grammatically/syntactically correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I came across the sentence:

> "He had spent part of his childhood in the home of an older Swedish relatives."

Is this grammatically and syntactically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It appears to be a typo or misprint.  It should have been either...

> ...in the home of an older Swedish relative.

or

> ...in the home of older Swedish relatives.

Which one makes the most sense would require reading the context surrounding the sentence.

Comment: Doesn't fall under the category as with "an additional five apples," does it?